# state city dropdown not working

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I found country state city dropdown code online. But i just wanted state and city. so made some changes, bt its not working properly, this is the edited code, please tell me whts wrong with it?
thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.1 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<font face="Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular">
<head>

<!--start head-->


<title>State - City Dropdown</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

// State lists
var cities = new Array();

cities['Gujarat'] = new Array('Ahmedabad','Vadodara','Surat');
cities['Rajasthan'] = new Array('Jaisalmer','Chittod','Jaipur');
cities['maharashtra'] = new Array('Mumbai','Pune','Nasik');


// City lists


function setcities() {
  stateSel = document.getElementById('state');
  cityList = cities[stateSel.value];
  changeSelect('city', cityList, cityList);

}



function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;
  for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
    selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
  }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  setcities();
});
</script>



<fieldset style="width: 300px;">
<legend><strong>Make your selection</strong></legend>
<p>
<!-- <form name="test" method="POST" action="processingpage.php"> -->
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">States:</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<select name="State" id="State" onChange="setcities();">
  <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
  <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
  <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">City:</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<select name="City" id="city" onChange="setcities();">
  <option value="">Please select a City </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</fieldset>
</font></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javaScript attributes are Case Sensitive
You have Used state for State and maharashtra for Maharashtra Correct it or
Use the following Code,

```
<!--start head-->


<title>State - City Dropdown</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

// State lists
var cities = new Array();

cities['Gujarat'] = new Array('Ahmedabad','Vadodara','Surat');
cities['Rajasthan'] = new Array('Jaisalmer','Chittod','Jaipur');
cities['Maharashtra'] = new Array('Mumbai','Pune','Nasik');


// City lists


function setcities() {
  stateSel = document.getElementById('State');
  cityList = cities[stateSel.value];
  changeSelect('city', cityList, cityList);

}



function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;
  for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
    selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
  }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  setcities();
});
</script>



<fieldset style="width: 300px;">
<legend><strong>Make your selection</strong></legend>
<p>
<!-- <form name="test" method="POST" action="processingpage.php"> -->
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">States:</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<select name="State" id="State" onChange="setcities();">
  <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
  <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
  <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">City:</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<select name="City" id="city" onChange="setcities();">
  <option value="">Please select a City </option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</fieldset>
</font></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the id `state` to `State` and change `cities['maharashtra']` to `cities['Maharashtra']`

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/Jehd2/1/)**

```
function setcities() {
 var  stateSel = document.getElementById("State");
    console.log(stateSel);
  cityList = cities[stateSel.value];
  changeSelect('city', cityList, cityList);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The html component you declared is with id as '**State**' but you reading for '**state**'. Best practice will be using **jQuery** in the project. jQuery will take care of the cross browser issues and will be handy while coding.