# State city dropdown list

Tags: javascript

I tested this [state city dropdown not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475908/state-city-dropdown-not-working)

JavaScript code for state and city drop down. My question is when this prog runs the first city from the respective state is displayed , one cannot select another city in the same state.
 Eg: 
In Maharashtra state the city which gets displayed is Mumbai. IF i select pune from the list, it does not work. I want pune or nasik city to be also selected. Any idea ?

Comment: Add an example of what you have tried please

Comment: A live demo would be helpful

Comment: @willem here you will get what i ment. http://screencast.com/t/k5sPej9gKMZ

Comment: @THOMAS Sorry but a screenshot isn't very helpful, I want to see an somewhat isolated `code` example of what your code looks like, and what you have tried.

Comment: Made a minor change in the coding. Removed onChange="setcities(); and then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small change you need to do Please modify the html
from

```
<select name="City" id="city" onChange="setcities();">
 <option value="">Please select a City </option>
</select>
```

to

```
<select name="City" id="city"">
 <option value="">Please select a City </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to replace the SECOND dropdown with a multiselect dropdown.
here you can find good examples:
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
class connect {

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            /    estabilish connection with the db credentials

            if (!$conn) {
                //    display error
            }
            return $conn;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //    throw exception
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
?>
<?php
include_once("conf.php");
include_once("function.php");
$object_function = new functions;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
<div>
    <select  name="select_data" id="select_state">
        <option>Please select</option>
        <?php
        $country_details = $object_function->state_details();
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < count($country_details)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country_details[$i]['STATEID'] ?>"><?php echo $country_details[$i]['STATENAME']; ?></option>
            <?php
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select  name="select_data" id="select_city">
        <option>Please select</option>

    </select>
</div>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once("conf.php");
class functions extends connect {
    private $conn = '';
    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = parent::__construct();
    }
    public function state_details() {
        try {
            $all_states = "select * from LWSTATEMASTER";
            $state_connection = oci_parse($this->conn, $all_states);
            $execute_query = oci_execute($state_connection);
            while ($state_row = oci_fetch_assoc($state_connection)) {
                $state_rows[] = $state_row;
            }
            return $state_rows;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function city_details($country_data) {
        try {
            global $conn;
            $rows = array();
            $state_value = $country_data['state_value'];
            $all_cities = "select CITYID,CITYNAME from LWCITYMASTER where STATEID ='$state_value'";
            $city_connection = oci_parse($this->conn, $all_cities);
            $execute_query = oci_execute($city_connection);

            while ($city_row = oci_fetch_assoc($city_connection)) {
                $city_rows[] = $city_row;
            }
            $this->fetch_city_eachrows($city_rows);
        } catch (Exception$e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function fetch_city_eachrows($city_rows) {
        try {
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < count($city_rows)) {
                echo "<option value= " . $rows[$i]['CITYID'] . ">" . $city_rows[$i]['CITYNAME'] . "</option>";
                $i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

$obj = new functions;
if (isset($_REQUEST['type']) == 'country') {
    $country_data = $_REQUEST;
    $obj->city_details($country_data);
}
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#select_state").change(function () {
            var val = $('#select_state').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'function.php',
                data: {'state_value': val, 'type': 'country'},
              `enter code here`  success: function (response) {
                    $("#select_city").html(response);
                    $("#select_city").show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some description as well so that we can understand what is going on and how this code helps in solving the problem.

Comment: Hi Mohammad,  I have used here oracle 10g and PHP version 5.7.I have defines the data base connectivity in a constructor of class connect and extend it in class function and used the constructor of connect class in class function, so that it will automatically invoked whenever the object of class function call. oci_parse and oci_execute and oracle 10g functions to connect and execute the query.  Simply, I have given ajax request when change state  display it in city dropdown. Hope, u understand.  Thanks for your feedback.